# Can KNN be better than other classifiers?

Tags: classification, svm, random-forest, knn

As Known, there are classifiers that have a training or a learning step, like SVM or Random Forest. On the other hand, KNN does not have.

Can KNN be better than these classifiers?
If no, why?

If yes, when, how and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main answer is **yes, it can due to no free lunch theorem implications**. FLT can be loosley stated as (in terms of classification)

> There is no universal classifier which is consisntenly better at any task than others

It can also be (not very strictly) inverted

> For each (well defined) classifier there exists a dataset where it is the best one

And in particular - kNN is well-defined classifier, in particular it is **consistent** with any distibution, which means that given infinitely many training points it converges to the optimal, Bayesian separator.

So can it be better than SVM or RF? Obviously! When? There is no clear answer. First of all in supervised learning you often actually get just **one training set** and try to fit the best model. In such scenario any model can be the best one. When statisticians/theoretical ML try to answer whether one model is better than another, we actually try to test "what would happen if we would have ifinitely many training sets" - so we look at the expected value of the behaviour of the classifiers. In such setting, we often show that SVM/RF is better than KNN. But it **does not** mean that they are **always** better. It only means, that for randomly selected dataset you should expect KNN to work worse, but this is only **probability**. And as you can always win in a lottery (no matter the odds!) you can also always win with KNN (just to be clear - KNN has bigger chances of being a good model than winning a lottery :-)).

What are particular examples? Let us for example consider a rotated XOR problem.

[image]

If the true decision boundaries are as above, and you only have this four points. Obviously 1NN will be much better than SVM (with dot, poly or rbf kernel) or RF. It should also be true once you include more and more training points.

Answer (score -1):

"In general kNN would not be expected to exceed SVM or RF. When kNN does, that says something very interesting about the training data. If many doublets are present i the data set, a nearest neighbor algorithm works very well."

I heard the argument something like as written by Claudia Perlich in this podcast:
http://www.thetalkingmachines.com/blog/2015/6/18/working-with-data-and-machine-learning-in-advertizing

My intuitive understanding of why RF and SVM is better kNN in generel: All algorithms basicly assume some local similarity, such that samples very alike gets classified alike. kNN can only choose the most similar samples by distance(or some other global kernel). So the samples which could influence a prediction on kNN would exists within a hyper sphere for the Euclidean distance kernel. RF and SVM can learn other definitions of locality which could stretch far by some features and short by others. Also the propagation of locality could take up many learned shapes, and these shapes can differ through out the feature space.

Comment: There are some important errors here. kNN does not use "other global kernel", rather - any given similariy measure. "would exist within a hyper sphere for the Euclidean distance" is also false, you can easily define metric to use with kNN which does not have this property.

Comment: @lejlot  Yes I got similarity measure and kernels a little mixed up. Similarity measure identifies nearest neighbors and a kernel can weight influence of neighbors by similarity measure. But I see "would exist within a hyper sphere for the Euclidean distance" as correct, as I wrote Euclidean not Minkowski etc. . My point is the similarity measure is not learned, but stated prior to training.

Comment: Kernel has many meanings in ML, but it should not be used as a name of a weighting scheme, especially not in classification, where kernels are either density-estimation building blocks, or elements of kernel trick introducing projection to reproducing hilbert kernel spaces.

And next to hypersphere - similarity measure is stated prior to training, but does not have to be fixed to Euclidean, thus it is false. Furthermore, for each testing point, this hypersphere has different radius (and in particular can contain whole input space).

Comment: If right or wrong I have no strong opinion, but kernel is certainly being used, check this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kknn/kknn.pdf

Comment: And you see - this is different meaning that you used. Here they mean, that their implementation actually creates **local kernel density estimator** and this is a meaning of kernel. This has nothing to do with the general approach to kNN, which might use **any similarity measure**. Their approach **is not a vanilla kNN**.

Comment: and my state had the clause "for Euclidean distance kernel" thus correct

Comment: Ok, my final comment to not extend it: no, your statements are false for kNN. Even for their implementation you can use **non Euclidean metric**!.

Comment: Statement on hyper spheres is still correct, I was just giving a simple example with a clause of only Euclidean Distance considered. I already pointed that out in the first comment and last comment.